# Асинхроность при постановке команд в очередь

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ajax запросы отрабатывают верно: получение статуса команды, удаление команды, постановка в очередь. Не могу решить проблему, при клике осуществляет отправку команд на сервер. В случае перезагрузки <kbd>F5</kbd>, сбрасываются все инпуты с измененными значениями, хотя должны сохраниться текущие значения пока не будет выполнена отмена.

```js
var initialDeviceSettingsSets = $('#ikz-settings-sets').get(0).outerHTML;
var currentDeviceSettingsSets;
var statusSuccessSets;

initialSetsConfigs = result.device_settings.bonding;


var last = true;
var cur_Vals;

var initialMasDeviceSettingsSets;
var val_KSPD_Obj;



$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: antraksHost + '/cur_vals?uuid=' + uuidOfElement + '&last=' + last,
  async: false,
  success: function(results) {


    cur_Vals = [];


    val_KSPD_Obj = {};

    val_KSPD_Obj['Peers'] = cur_Vals;



  },
  error: function(results) {

  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: window.antraksHost + '/device/' + uuidOfElement + '/change_settings_status?key=SetBinding',
  async: false,
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(resultSetBinding) {

    if (resultSetBinding.status == 'Command to change this setting is in queue') {
      result.device_settings.bonding = JSON.parse(resultSetBinding.values);
      statusSuccessSets = true;
    }
  },
  error: function(resultSetBinding) {
    console.error('error /change_settings_status?key=SetBinding');
  }
});

if (result.protocol == 'iec104') {

  delete result.device_settings.set_number;
  result.device_settings['bonding'] = val_KSPD_Obj;

  var initialMasDeviceSettingsSets = [];

  for (key in result.device_settings.bonding) {
    //                            delete result.device_settings.set_number;  
    initialMasDeviceSettingsSets.push(key);

  }

  $('#convert-json-to-html-tree-sets').append(convertJsonToHtmlTree(result.device_settings.bonding, typeOfDevice, '', initialMasDeviceSettingsSets));


} else if (Object.keys(result.device_settings.bonding).length != 0) {

  $('#convert-json-to-html-tree-sets').append(convertJsonToHtmlTree(result.device_settings.bonding, typeOfDevice, '', initialMasDeviceSettingsSets));

} else {
  $('#convert-json-to-html-tree-sets').append('empty');
}



if (statusSuccessSets == true) {
  $('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').removeClass('settings-for-device-button-not-press');
  $('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').addClass('settings-for-device-button-press');
  $('#ikz-settings-sets input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').text(localeTextCancelTransfer);
}

// при изменении значения input-а обновлять html и реагирование кнопки
$('#ikz-settings-sets input').on('input', function() {
  $(this).addClass('changedInput');

  if ($(this).attr('type') != 'checkbox') {
    // $(this).attr('value', $(this).val() );

    currentDeviceSettingsSets = ($('#ikz-settings-sets').get(0).outerHTML);

    if (initialDeviceSettingsSets != currentDeviceSettingsSets) {

      $('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').addClass('settings-for-device-button-not-press');
    } else {
      $('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').removeClass('settings-for-device-button-not-press');
    }
  }
});

$('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').click(function() {
      if (
        $('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').hasClass('settings-for-device-button-press') ||
        $('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').hasClass('settings-for-device-button-not-press')
      ) {
        if ($('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').hasClass('settings-for-device-button-press')) {
          if (confirm(localeRemoveCommandFromCommandQueue) == true) {
            $.ajax({
              url: window.antraksHost + '/device/' + uuidOfElement + '/change_settings_request?key=SetBinding',
              async: false,
              type: 'DELETE',
              success: function(result) {
                // location.reload();
              },
              error: function(result) {
                console.error('error DELETE SetBinding ' + result);
              }
            });
          }
        } else {
          if (confirm(localeAddCommandToTheCommandQueue) == true) {
            $('#frame-compl-sets .changedInput').each(function() {
                var evalCodeSets = 'initialSetsConfigs';
                // var evalCodeSets;
                var nameAttrIdSets = $(this).attr('id');

                nameAttrIdSets = nameAttrIdSets.replace('[', '.').replace(']', '');
                nameAttrIdSets = nameAttrIdSets.replace('[', '.').replace(']', '');
                nameAttrIdSets = nameAttrIdSets.split('.');

                for (var i = 0; i < nameAttrIdSets.length; i++) {
                  if (nameAttrIdSets[i] = 'Peers') {
                    evalCodeSets = 'initialSetsConfigs';

                    else {
                      evalCodeSets = evalCodeSets + '["' + nameAttrIdSets[i] + '"]';

                    }
                  }

                  eval(evalCodeSets + ' = ' + $(this).val());
                });

              var sendSetSetsConfigs = JSON.stringify(initialSetsConfigs);

              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: window.antraksHost + '/device/' + uuidOfElement + '/change_settings',
                async: false,
                data: {
                  key: 'SetBinding',
                  value: sendSetSetsConfigs
                },
                success: function(result) {
                  $('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').removeClass('settings-for-device-button-not-press');
                  $('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').addClass('settings-for-device-button-press');
                  $('#ikz-settings-sets input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                  $('#settings-for-device-device_settings-sets').text(localeTextCancelTransfer);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                  console.error('error change_settings sets');
                }
              });
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: ```...должны зацементироваться с текущими значениями...``` Под текущими значениями вы понимаете те, что ввел пользователь до нажатия кнопки на форме? Или те, что пришли в момент  загрузки страницы и первоначально были выведены в элементах формы?

Comment: Действительно. момент немного некорректно звучит. Под текущими значениями. имеются те , что пользователь вел перед отправкой. При перезугрузки они должны вернуться (... пока не будет выполнена отмена).

Comment: Для сохранения промежуточных значений элементов вашей формы, до их отправки ajax'ом -  можете воспользоваться [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage).

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит. Дело в том, что отправляю эти изменения post запросом и получаю get запросом по условию с изменившимся статусом 'Command to change this setting is in queue' . данный скрипт успешно работает с одним объектом + uuidOfElement + , но для второго типа он не отрабатывает. Видимо где нарушена логика работы скрипта

Comment: Проблемы получения данных get запросом    ----   Дело в том, что отправляю данные с изменениями настроек post запросом и получаю get запросом по условию с изменившимся статусом 'Command to change this setting is in queue' . данный скрипт успешно работает с одним объектом + uuidOfElement + , но для другого  uuidOfElement не возвращает нужные данные при повторном обращении. В логах видно что команды добавляются для одного uuid, а потом пыстаюсь получить get запросом для другого uuid . Поэтому не могу их вывести в элементы формы (зацементировать)